# Java loop on interface

Tags: java, interface, enums

I have 10 interfaces `(IInterface1, IInterface2...IInterface10)` that extends one interface named `Interface`, and I have an enum `IEnume` with 10 values.

Currently I am doing this:

**This is a pseudo code**

```
type = some enum values.
switch(type){
IEnume.value1:
if (IInterface1.class.isAssignableFrom(myClass)) {system.out.println("something";)}
IEnume.value2:
if (IInterface2.class.isAssignableFrom(myClass)) {system.out.println("something";)}
IEnume.value3:
if (IInterface3.class.isAssignableFrom(myClass)) {system.out.println("something";)}
...
...
...
IEnume.value10:
if (IInterface10.class.isAssignableFrom(myClass)) {system.out.println("something";)}
}
```

as you see, it is the same code for each enum value, the only difference is the `IInterface`

I made all my interfaces extend the `IInterface`.Does that help to make just one thing like this:

```
IInterface i;
type = some enum values.
    switch(type){
    IEnume.value1:
    i = IInterface1
    IEnume.value2:
    i = IInterface2

    ...
    ...
    ...
    IEnume.value10:
    i = IInterface10
    }
```

so that then I can do this:

```
if(i.class.isAssignableFrom(myClass)
```

The problem is that I couldn't do

```
i = IInterface1
```

#### Update one

my situation is that i am readying the name of the interface from a file and the actual class implementation for it from the same file.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc i can't do new on interface man

Comment: I hope the guy who down vote, tell me what wrong i did. i showed u the problem and how i solve it. i guess this is a valid question. otherwise, tell me my mistake so i can improve next time.

Comment: I read the question, but I still have no idea what you need this for. This sounds ridiculously overcomplicated, you should show how you use this so we can find a good answer.

Comment: I really have wonder if you want to use a [Visitor Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) here.

Comment: (I did no downvote, but my comment still stands.)

Comment: @mafu i tried to ask if it is possible to not rewrite the same code for each enum value. i showed u my thinking which is make a general interface for all the interfaces. and the problem **obviously** that i can do `interface = interface`, do u have any solution please? thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible to see the actual java code?  I struggle to understand what you are asking.

Comment: What is the relationship between `myClass` and the `print` function? Are you using a `switch` statement to bypass standard object inheritance?

Comment: i update the question guys, thanks u for loocking

Answer (score 2):

Why not just have a method on the `IEnume` class:

```
enum IEnume {
    value1(IInterface1.class),
    value2(IInterface2.class);

    private Class<? extends IInterface> iClass;
    private IEnume(Class<? extends IInterface> iClass) { this.iClass = iClass; }

    public boolean isInterfaceAssignable(Class<?> clazz) {
        return this.iClass.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
if(type.isInterfaceAssignable(myClass)) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: This approach could possibly be extended to use a static array of all interfaces implementing the base interface, filled via reflection right after assembly loading. It would spare us from keeping the enum up to date. Not sure if that would be useful tho. (And assuming this is required at all - still waiting for OP to explain the scenario in more detail.)

Comment: From the information given after the first update, this seems to be the logical answer to the question. You have my upvote.

Comment: i tried to do `ICustomPublishingNeedsService(ICustomPublishingNeeds.class);` inside my enum but i get `The constructor PluginTypes(Class<ICustomPublishingNeeds>) is undefined`

Comment: For the constructor, try using arg of type `Class<? extends ICustomPublishingNeeds>`

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that I couldn't do
>
> i = IInterface1

What you can do is:

```
Class cls = Interface.class;
cls.isAssignableFrom(anotherClass);
```

Or (as suggested by @talex) you can use to get rid of unparameterized warning:

```
Class<? extends Interface> cls = Interface.class;
cls.isAssignableFrom(anotherClass);
```

Comment: and where is the assignment? I couldn't do this: `Class<IPlugin> cls = ICustomPublishingNeeds.class;` i got compiler error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<ICustomPublishingNeeds> to Class<IPlugin>`

Comment: updated the answer. (You'll have a warning though, since the type Class isn't parameterized)

Comment: Or you can do ` Class<? extends IPlugin> cls `

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell what you really want to achieve here, so I hope this answer is going in the right direction.

Could you add a method `void Print_something()` to `IInterface` and simply call it instead of doing the whole `switch` thing? You could have all other interfaces extend this 'base' interface, so all instances will be forced to implement it. No need to check the actual types at all - much simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: Nice. That is, after all, what interfaces are for.

Comment: Assuming there's a relationship between `myClass` and the `print` function, the entire thing could be replaced with `myClass.printSomething()`

Comment: i don't need to call any method from that interface, i am doing class validation, can u read my update please

Comment: could you check the other answer please? i have a problem and the user seems to be left already

Answer (score 0):

You can store the interface in the enum as already suggested, or you can make a map:

```
map.put(IEnume.value1, IInterface1.class);
map.put(IEnume.value2, IInterface2.class);
map.put(IEnume.value3, IInterface3.class);
...
map.put(IEnume.value10, IInterface10.class);
```

Then, to perform the validation:

```
if (map.get(type).isAssignableFrom(myClass)){System.out.println("something");}
```

Comment: could the map be `Map<PluginTypes, IPlugin> map = new HashMap<PluginTypes, IPlugin>();` ?

Comment: Sure, that's the idea; I omitted variable declaration for brevity.

Comment: that doesn't work, i did this `map.put(PluginTypes.ICustomPublishingNeedsService,
    ICustomPublishingNeeds.class);` but i got compiler error `Cannot refer to the static enum field PluginTypes.ICustomPublishingNeedsService within an initializer`

Comment: i did that in the constructor of the enum, should i do that in another method?

Comment: i put it in another method and i got this error `The method put(PluginTypes, IPlugin) in the type Map<PluginTypes,IPlugin> is not applicable for the arguments (PluginTypes, Class<ICustomPublishingNeeds>)`

Comment: Do it in the class in which you do the validation. This map is its internal thing, it is not important to the outer world (other classes) to know how the validation is done (switch statement, enum methods, map, etc).

Comment: still there is the same problem that answer from `Stewart` produces, i hope you help me here, Stewart has left without continuing his answer

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Sorry, the map declaration should be `Map<PluginTypes, Class<? extends IPlugin>> map = new HashMap<PluginTypes, Class<? extends IPlugin>>();`. We are storing the `class` objects in the map, not the actual instances of the plugins.